# Nativescript image thumbnails

Tags: angular, image, android-camera, nativescript, thumbnails

I'm using Angular 8.0 + NativeScript 6.0 with the NativeScript camera plugin to take pictures and store them in the gallery in my app. When I do a listing of the images I've taken in the app it's loading the full scale image which slows down the whole app.

Is there a way I can get the thumbnail of the gallery image instead of the full image?

Currently I save the URL of the full image in my database by storing it in a string called receipt_url and passing that to the backend. Here is the code where I take the picture and store the URL;

```
onTakeReceiptTap(args) {
    requestPermissions().then(
        () => {
            takePicture({width: 640, height: 480, keepAspectRatio: true})
                .then((imageAsset: any) => {
                    this.receiptImage = imageAsset;

                    console.log("Taken receipt")
                    let that = this;

                    if (imageAsset.android) {
                        this._dataItem.receipt_url = imageAsset.android;
                    } else if (imageAsset.ios) {
                        this._dataItem.receipt_url = imageAsset.ios;
                    }

                }, (error) => {
                    console.log("Error: " + error);
                });
        },
        () => alert('permissions rejected')
    );
} // onTakeReceiptTap
```

When performing a listing I simply get all the records from the database which includes the receipt url and I display the picture like so;

```
        <Image rowspan="2" col="1" [src]="item.receipt_url" stretch="aspectFit"></Image>
```

Given all I have is a URL I'm wondering if Android/iOS create a thumbnail in which I could get the URL and store that as well and use it in my listing or do I have to create the thumbnail myself somehow and either send the thumbnail from the backend or save the URL for the thumbnail?

**Update: Virtual Scrolling**

I tried adding the virtual scrolling like so and tried different heights (150, 500 & 1000) all of which are still very slow and jerky to scroll.

```
  <GridLayout row="1" columns="*, auto">
    <RadListView [items]="dataItems"
                 [filteringFunction]="filterItems"
                 pullToRefresh="true"
                 (pullToRefreshInitiated)="onPullToRefreshInitiated($event)">

      <ScrollView height="500">
        <ng-template tkListItemTemplate let-item="item">
          <StackLayout orientation="vertical">
            <GridLayout class="itemContainer" rows="50,*" columns="*,100">

              <!-- Currently these images are full size and slowing down the listing -->
              <Image rowspan="2" col="1" [src]="item.picture_url" stretch="aspectFit"></Image>

              <Label row="0" col="0" class="nameLabel" [text]="item.name"></Label>

            </GridLayout>

            <!-- <StackLayout orientation="horizontal">
                 <Label text="Price: "></Label>
                 <Label class="gross_centsLabel" [text]="item.gross_cents"></Label>
                 </StackLayout> -->
          </StackLayout>
        </ng-template>
      </ScrollView>

    </RadListView>
  </GridLayout>
```

**Update: using ImageSource**

If I try using ImageSource for each image in the list then I get the following error;

```
LOG from device Galaxy S8: ERROR Error: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 36578316 byte allocation with 16269904 free bytes and 15MB until OOM
```

Here is how I was setting the ImageSources;

```
loadData() {
    this._dataItemService.listing()
        .subscribe(loadedItems => {
            loadedItems.forEach((itemObject) => {
                itemObject.picture = fromFile(itemObject.picture_url);
                this._dataItems.unshift(itemObject) ;
            });
        })
}
```

The 'picture' attribute is setup as a ImageSource in the data model.

**Update: Saving thumbnails**

I managed to save a thumbnail on the frontend and display this in my listing. Now the listing is much faster.

```
                    const source = new ImageSource();
                    source.fromAsset(imageAsset)
                        .then((imageSource: ImageSource) => {
                            const folderPath = knownFolders.documents().path;
                            const fileName = "test.jpg";
                            const filePath = path.join(folderPath, fileName);
                            const saved: boolean = imageSource.saveToFile(filePath, "jpg");
                            if (saved) {
                                console.log("Gallery: " + this._dataItem.picture_url);
                                console.log("Saved: " + filePath);
                                console.log("Image saved successfully!");
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: The scrolling problem might come from the fact that your inserting a `ScrollView` inside the `RadListView`

Comment: The returned image asset will already have resized image, but when you load it via image url it won't be  effective. Create image source from image asset and assign the same no the image component.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be possible to [downsample](https://docs.nativescript.org/performance-optimizations/images-optimisations#using-decodeheight-and-decodewidth-properties) images on Android but they don't seem to talk about any optimizations for IOS.

But I can *suggest* two approaches that could be even combined and also work across both platforms:

1. Utilize [Virtual Scroll](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview#virtual-scrolling) provided by the Angular CDK (assuming you use Angular 7)
2. Explore the feasibility of creating thumbnails on the client or the back end as you've mentioned with your own implementation or a lib like [imagemagick](https://github.com/yourdeveloper/node-imagemagick#resizeoptions-callbackerr-stdout-stderr)

Comment: I thought there would be a standard way of doing this on the frontend. Angular/iOS must do this for their respective gallery of photos.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you can create the thumbnails on your backend.
I'd recommend using [Sharp](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/) (or [libvips](https://github.com/libvips/libvips)) as is faster.

Another good thing you can do is avoid using `*ngFor` for lists that you know will get lengthy. Use [`ListView`](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/ng-ui-widgets/listview#listview) instead.

`ListView` recycles the views and renders/loads just the ones the app needs. Thus avoiding loading into memory views that are not being seen.

```
<ListView [items]="countries" (itemTap)="onItemTap($event)" class="list-group">
    <ng-template let-item="item">
        <GridLayout class="itemContainer" rows="50,*" columns="*,100">
              <!-- Currently these images are full size and slowing down the listing -->
              <Image rowspan="2" col="1" [src]="item.picture_url" stretch="aspectFit"></Image>
              <Label row="0" col="0" class="nameLabel" [text]="item.name"></Lab
        </GridLayout>
    </ng-template>
</ListView>
```

### Update: Fixing the `RadListView` implementation

In your implementation of the `RadListView`, there is a `ScrollView` inside.

Remember that:

- Inside the RadListView you have to use only the template for the items: `<ng-template tkListItemTemplate let-item="item">...`
- The `RadListView` (as the `ListView`) is a scrolling widget. You don't need a `ScrollView`.

```
    <RadListView [items]="dataItems"
                 [filteringFunction]="filterItems"
                 pullToRefresh="true"
                 (pullToRefreshInitiated)="onPullToRefreshInitiated($event)">
        <ng-template tkListItemTemplate let-item="item">
            <GridLayout class="itemContainer" rows="50,*" columns="*,100">

              <!-- Currently these images are full size and slowing down the listing -->
              <Image rowspan="2" col="1" [src]="item.picture_url" stretch="aspectFit"></Image>

              <Label row="0" col="0" class="nameLabel" [text]="item.name"></Label>

            </GridLayout>
        </ng-template>
    </RadListView>
```